# Difference between "I can understand" vs. "I understand"

Tags: modal-verbs

I told my sister the following:

> 1. I **can understand** that you must be missing us.

or should I have said,

> 2. I **understand** that you must be missing us.

What is the correct sentence here?

Comment: The "correct" sentence will be the sentence that is more appropriate to what it is that you were trying to communicate in that situation that you were in. So, what was the context? If you provide that, then it might be easier for us to explain the difference in meaning between those two options.

Comment: What it comes down to is this: were you trying to communicate that ***you understood*** that someone must be missing you, or were you trying to communicate that ***you* could *understand*** that someone must be missing you?

Comment: You have two sentences that are both perfectly fine grammatically but have slightly different meaning. So asking which one is right or wrong is missing the point. You'd need to tell what exactly you want to express, and then you can ask which sentence matches that better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I **can understand** that you must be missing us.

Here, you are adding some distance or uncertainty regarding the topic. You *are able* to understand, but you might not be quite there yet. It might have some followup:

> I **can understand** that you must be missing us, but wouldn't things be better if you came back?

As for:

> I **understand** that you must be missing us.

this is a direct statement and means just what is written.
However, as in many situations, context is important to decide the best way to write what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Which is correct? **Both are**.

However, I think *can* adds **a bit** of your 'efforts' to understand someone/thing.

However, when it comes to "I", I think more frequent is using it **without** 'can'.

[Ngram supports me!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i%20can%20understand%2C%20i%20understand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ci%20can%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ci%20understand%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Is it grammatically wrong to say "I can understand." ?

Comment: @dexterous_stranger No. There are over a thousand results for *I can understand* in the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA): http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=39153039